# ValidationSummary not showing in message box

Tags: asp.net

I know what the problem is, I just don't know why or how to solve it.
Basically I have two RequiredFieldValidators that are disabled by default.
When the user clicks the button, they are checked to see if they should be enabled.

```
HCAmountValidator.Enabled = HealthCareReimbursementChkBox.Checked; <-- enables req validator
DCAmountValidator.Enabled = DependentCareReimbursementChkBox.Checked; <-- enables req validator

Page.Validate(); 
if (!Page.IsValid)
    return;
```

In that last block of code, it checks validation, then returns, but all I get is the error text and the summary at the bottom of the screen. The message box won't pop up.

Comment: You've verified, I assume, that if you leave the validators enabled all the time, the message box pops up?  Because there could be all kinds of reasons, from an omitted setting to a javascript error, why you might not see a popup.

Comment: Yes. When they are enabled from the get-go, it runs the messagebox just fine. It's only when I enable them later that it does not pop up, yet the Summary Message still pops up

Answer (score 0):

I cleared my web browser cache and it started working again.